# Please help me formulate (and solve) a differential equation for a practical DIY problem concerning air sterilization (for covid)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

[Here](https://old.reddit.com/r/COVIDProjects/comments/jtlfs6/diy_air_sterilizer_with_schematics_and_shopping/) I present the DIY air sterilisation project which this is about.

I want to calculate the overall sterilization rate of the device under some simplifying assumptions. (UVC is the hard ultra violet (UV) light killing the germs.)

[schema drawing](http://%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vQXLE0yCNr574Sws-DpftJPp0AL7ocSwKTYFq6gubOucxGQFJLwNJsAw1x5-EvL9ZK37m2k3ypyxuCE/pub?w=960&h=720%22%3E)
[image]
I have

- the effective UVC power $E$ of my germicidal lamp. The lamp is a Hg-"neon" tube along the axis of the cylindrical device.
- the length $L$ of the lamp
- the radius $R_l$ of the lamp
- the inner radius $R_c$ of the cylinder
- a radius-invariant constant airflow through the cylinder (we are way into turbulent flow) with the speed $v$, so that I can calculate a mean residence time of the virus traveling through the killzone for
- a time $t =  L/v$
- the UVC irradiation intensity $I$ at a given radius $r$ in the cylinder $I(r) = \frac{E}{2\pi \, L \, r}$
- a irradiation dose $d(r) = I(r)*t$
- a virus-specific susceptibilty rate $k$ to calculate the specific killrate $P(r)=1-e^{-k \, d(r)}$
- a infinitisimal thin hollow cylinder (thickness $dr$) at radius $r$ around the axis of the cylinder with the volume $V(r) = 2  \pi  L \, r \, dr$ , which is proportional to the amount of germs exposed to the specific irradiation dose $d(r)$.

Now I look for the overall kill rate for the volume between $R_l$ and $R_c$.

Would it be correct to calculate  $\frac{1}{R_c - R_l}\cdot\int_{R_l}^{R_c} P(r) \cdot V(r)dr =  \frac{1}{R_c - R_l}\cdot\int_{R_l}^{R_c}2  \pi  L \, r \, (1-e^{-k   \frac{E}{2\pi\,v \, r}})   dr$ ?

Is that the differential equation I need?
What is a solution for that?

Here are some matlab lines which are unfortunatly not correct as the result is independent of most of the variables.

```
syms R_l R_c L r E k v V(r);
u = symunit;

assume(0<R_l <R_c);

t = L*u.m/(v*u.m/u.s);
I = E*u.W/(2*pi*L*u.m*r*u.m);
d = I * t;
P = 1-exp(-k*(u.cm^2/u.mJ)*d);
diff(V*u.m^3) == 2*pi* L*u.m * r*u.m *diff(r*u.m);
killrate = V*P


latex(killrate);

mean_killrate = int( killrate ,r, R_l, R_c)/(R_c -R_l);

mean_killrate_small = eval( subs(mean_killrate, {R_l R_c L E k v}, {0.016/2 0.125/2 0.113 0.95 0.41 3}))

mean_killrate_medium = eval( subs(mean_killrate, {R_l R_c L E k v}, {0.016/2 0.125/2 0.205 4 0.41 3}))

mean_killrate_large = eval( subs(mean_killrate, {R_l R_c L E k v}, {0.040/2 0.125/2 0.51 27 0.41 3}))
```

edit: updated the matlab code to use `diff()` for differential terms and measurement units (to find inconcistencies in the equations).

Comment: A diagram of the situation would help quite a bit.

Comment: you mean a pic of the geometry, @K.defaoite ?

Comment: Yes. It would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: @K.defaoite added it already. does it help clarify things?

Comment: Greatly. I'll give this problem a try.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "overkill rate"? I'm a bit confused overall - what is the exact problem you are trying to solve? Are you trying to determine the lethality of this lamp to viral cells? Are you trying to compute the power per unit area of the lamp between $R_l$ and $R_c$?

Comment: in the first line i called it "overall sterilization rate of the device". Each infinitisimal small hollow cylinder has its own UVC intensity and its own sterilization rate. I want to calculate the overall sterilization rate. one thought i had was to calculate the mean kill rate over all the slices with the term $\frac{1}{R_c-R_l}, but i am actually not sure if that is correct, because the volumes are not linar to the radius but quadratic- but are they?

Comment: I worked a little with matlab to solve this, but my result is obviously wrong as it is independet of most of the variables. i could share that, too.

Comment: As I see it, $P(r)$ should be written as $P(t,r)$ since it looks like it's supposed to represent the proportion of germs remaining after time $t$ at some radius $r$ - is that correct? If that's the case, is your aim to compute what proportion of germs will be left between radii $R_l$ and $R_c$ after some time $t$?

Comment: @K.defaoite I am not sure regarding $P(t,r)$. In my current approach $t$ is not a variable, it is a constant, because I assume (its a simplification) that all the germs cross the killzone in the same, constant time, because the airflow is uniform and the killzone is a cylindrical space. In reality the killzone is not homogenous as I make it, and for that reason the viruses spend different times in it. But for now I want to neglect that because I lack an idea of how to describe the killzone more accuratly. I only care about how many germs died in the device, not where or when they die.